# how do i do authentification on android

Tags: android, http, authentication, rest

I need to authenticate to use a rest web service.

I make a

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

an there must be a way to use `UsernamePasswordCredentials` on that client.

Can somebody please point me to a relevant example?

I have found some source code uding the HttpClient class in the org.apache.commons.SOMETHING_HTTP, but that doesn't exist on Android.

Cheers

Comment: In title, "Authentication" instead of "Authentification". Please also write "http" in the title.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you : http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/